# SvelteKit async load styles with strict CSP (no unsafe-inline) %sveltekit.nonce%?

Tags: content-security-policy, sveltekit

Is it possible to async load styles in SvelteKit `app.html` when using a strict Content Security Policy with no `unsafe-inline` ?

Let say I use a `script-src: 'self'` directive and I want to async load some styles with the pattern

```html
<link rel="preload" as="style" href="/styles.css" onload="this.rel='stylesheet'" />
```

This will expectedly generate an error

> Refused to execute inline event handler because it violates the following Content Security Policy directive: "script-src 'self' 'sha256-...'

My first thought was to somehow grab the nonce and inject it but :

- `%sveltekit.nonce%` is [not documented](https://github.com/sveltejs/kit/issues/4440)
- `nonce` is a script tag attribute

It seems like I should re-write the `link` tag without the `onload` and then set an event listener separatly.
But when I experiment with a

```html
<script nonce="%sveltekit.nonce%">console.log("hello")</script>
```

I get the following error when building

> Cannot use prerendering if page template contains %sveltekit.nonce%

Is this possible or is it an edge case since I'm in `app.html` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In my case since the script will not change I can use a hash to whitelist it.

So in the end I can make it work like this:

- Remove the `onload` attribute from the `link` tag:

```html
<link id="styles" rel="preload" as="style" href="/styles.css" />
```

- Put the `load` listener in a `script` tag in `app.html`:

```html
<script>
const styles = document.getElementById('styles');
window.addEventListener('load', (e) => {
    styles.setAttribute('rel', 'stylesheet');
});
</script>
```

- Generate the hash of the above script, for example with [this tool](https://strict-csp-codelab.glitch.me/csp_sha256_util.html), and add it to the whitelist:

```js
kit: {
    ...,
    csp: {
      mode: "auto",
      directives: {
        "script-src": [
          "self",
          "sha256-...",
        ],
      },
    },
  },
```

This way I get the benefits of speed with async loading and security with csp.

Answer (score 0):

You have an inline event handler

```
onload="this.rel='stylesheet'"
```

which you should rewrite with an event listener in a separate .js file. Otherwise you'll have to add 'unsafe-inline' to script-src. You might also be able to allow it with 'unsafe-hashes' and a hash, but not all browsers support 'unsafe-hashes' yet.